# git am error: “error: while searching for:”

Tags: git, patch, git-am

running `git am` I get error above. Comparing by hand I do not see any problem. May someone point me where the error is?

```
$ git am 0012-Do-not-die-when-something-nasty-happen-in-the-comman.patch --reject
Applying: Do not die when something nasty happen in the command
Checking patch lib/Devel/DebugHooks/CmdProcessor.pm...
error: while searching for:
    return 0   unless  $cmd  &&  exists $DB::commands->{ $cmd };

    # The command also should return defined value to keep interaction
    if( defined (my $result =  $DB::commands->{ $cmd }( $args_str )) ) {
        return $result   unless ref $result;

        # Allow commands to evaluate $expr at a debugged script context

error: patch failed: lib/Devel/DebugHooks/CmdProcessor.pm:14
Applying patch lib/Devel/DebugHooks/CmdProcessor.pm with 1 reject...
Rejected hunk #1.
Patch failed at 0001 Do not die when something nasty happen in the command
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

the .rej:

```
$ cat CmdProcessor.pm.rej 
diff a/lib/Devel/DebugHooks/CmdProcessor.pm b/lib/Devel/DebugHooks/CmdProcessor.pm  (rejected hunks)
@@ -14,7 +14,10 @@ sub process {
    return 0   unless  $cmd  &&  exists $DB::commands->{ $cmd };

    # The command also should return defined value to keep interaction
-   if( defined (my $result =  $DB::commands->{ $cmd }( $args_str )) ) {
+   my $result =  eval { $DB::commands->{ $cmd }( $args_str ) };
+   do{ print $DB::OUT "'$cmd' command died: $@"; return 1; }   if $@;
+
+   if( defined $result ) {
        return $result   unless ref $result;

        # Allow commands to evaluate $expr at a debugged script context
```

the source:

```
$ cat CmdProcessor.pm 
package Devel::DebugHooks::CmdProcessor;

sub process {
    my( $dbg ) =  shift;

    my( $cmd, $args_str ) =  shift =~ m/^([\w.]+)(?:\s+(.*))?$/;
    $args_str //=  '';


    return 0   unless  $cmd and exists $DB::commands->{ $cmd };

    # The command also should return defined value to keep interaction
    if( defined (my $result =  $DB::commands->{ $cmd }( $args_str )) ) {
        return $result   unless ref $result;

        # Allow commands to evaluate $expr at a debugged script context
        if( ref( $result ) eq 'HASH' ) {
            return $result->{ code }->(
                $args_str
                ,DB::eval( $result->{ expr } ) # FIX: it is not evaled at script context
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }
    else {
        return;
    }


    return 0;
}

1;
```

line endings are unix.

Trying to run `git apply` manually gives next error:

```
$ git apply CmdProcessor.pm.rej 
fatal: patch fragment without header at line 2: @@ -14,7 +14,10 @@ sub process {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

git is searching for the line

> return 0   unless  $cmd  **&&**  exists $DB::commands->{ $cmd };

but your code contains the line

> return 0   unless  $cmd **and** exists $DB::commands->{ $cmd };

(I marked the difference between **&&** and **and**) whence the patch does not apply.

You can find a nice tutorial about git conflict resolution [here](http://tedfelix.com/software/git-conflict-resolution.html).

Comment: fixing that does not resolve the problem the error: `No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
`

Comment: indeed; the patch does not apply since your code isn't the same. You can adapt your code manually using the information from the .rej file; then `git add` and then `git am --continue`

Comment: Yes, `git add` to stage changes allow me to `git am --continue`